# How with $faker->word get unique value?

Tags: laravel-5, factory

In laravel 5.8 app I make  tests and adding new user for any tests I encountered that line

```
$loggedUser= factory(User::class)->create();
```

raise error :

```
Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'Username pariatur' for key 'users_username_unique'
```

with factory defined :

```
$factory->define(App\User::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    $username= 'Username ' . $faker->word;
    return [
        'username' => $username,
```

I do not clear database, but how to make in series of tests get unqiue word for any test?

Comment: `$faker->unique()->word;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Faker provides three special providers like `unique()`, `optional()`, and `valid()`, to be called before any provider.

```
//use unique() before calling the method
$faker->unique()->name;
```